# bazel cmake target depend on configure_make target

Tags: c++, bazel

using `rules_foreign_cc` rules to compile libtins (a C++ packet capture lib using CMake) which is dependent on libpcap (C packet capture lib using configure/make). My BUILD file:

```
cmake(
    name = "libtins",
    lib_source = "@libtins//:all_srcs",
    deps = [":libpcap"]
)

configure_make(
    name = "libpcap",
    lib_source = "@libpcap//:all_srcs"
)
```

However the libtins CMake build can't find the compiled pcap lib (compiling the pcap target alone works):

```
CMake Error at /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/653770b95821fc65db7a3419f9c219c7/external/cmake-3.21.2-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find PCAP (missing: PCAP_LIBRARY PCAP_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /root/.cache/bazel/_bazel_root/653770b95821fc65db7a3419f9c219c7/external/cmake-3.21.2-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.21/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindPCAP.cmake:46 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

WORKSPACE file:

```
_ALL_CONTENT = """\
filegroup(
    name = "all_srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""
http_archive(
    name = "libtins",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    strip_prefix = "libtins-4.2",
    urls = ["https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/archive/refs/tags/v4.2.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "a9fed73e13f06b06a4857d342bb30815fa8c359d00bd69547e567eecbbb4c3a1",
)

http_archive(
    name = "libpcap",
    build_file_content = _ALL_CONTENT,
    strip_prefix = "libpcap-1.10.1",
    urls = ["https://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.10.1.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "ed285f4accaf05344f90975757b3dbfe772ba41d1c401c2648b7fa45b711bdd4",
)
```

Comment: Are you trying to build this on Linux?

Comment: yes, on ubuntu 2004

Comment: What does the command `dpkg -s libpcap0.8-dev` print?